# regex for date in javascript

Tags: javascript

how come when searching for dd/mm/yyyy in a string
this works:

```
/(\d\d?)\/(\d\d?)\/(\d{4})/
```

but this doesnt:

```
/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/d{4}/
```

Comment: `d{4}` is different from `\d{4}`

Comment: `\d\d?` is different from `\d{2}`, as well.

Comment: He's asking why a _particular_ regex didn't work and his question got closed as a duplicate... which is baffling to me. The two are not duplicates. A simple typo, yes... but not a duplicate of the linked question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo but you may not know *why*. Your second expression is looking for `d{4}` rather than `\d{4}`. Without that backslash, you're simply looking for the letter `d` rather than a number.

Additionally, the `{2}` means that you're looking for exactly 2 of the preceding character/group, so `1/1/2014` won't test positive. `{1,2}` will match one *to* two consecutive items. The first expression achieves that functionality with `\d\d?`. The `?` matches whether or not the preceding character/group exists.

```js
var tests = [
    { rx: /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/d{4}/, text: "10/10/dddd" },    // true
    { rx: /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/, text: "10/10/2014" },   // true
    { rx: /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/d{4}/, text: "1/1/2014" },      // false
    { rx: /\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/, text: "1/1/2014" }, // true
    { rx: /\d{1,2}/, text: "0" },                        // true
    { rx: /\d{1,2}/, text: "00" },                       // true
    { rx: /\d\d?/, text: "0" },                          // true
    { rx: /\d\d?/, text: "00" },                         // true
];

tests.forEach(function(t){
    console.log("rx: %s, text: %o, matches: %o", t.rx, t.text, t.rx.test(t.text));
});
```

<sub>See [MDN's Regular Expressions documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), particularly the explanations for [`\d`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-digit), [`?`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-questionmark), and [`{n,m}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-quantifier-range).</sub>

Comment: Just close as a typo, no need to make an answer from a comment.

Comment: @dystroy I didn't see a comment at the time of posting. That and I actually didn't notice the typo until I started drafting an answer.

Comment: yer sorry it was just a typo, im new to regular expressions thought i was doing it wrong